# Impossible to connect on 127.0.0.1 using MAMP

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, connection-timeout, prestashop-helper-classes

I am currently facing a big issue on a mission I have to do quickly for my job.

I had to install Prestashop 1.7.8 and create the entire website on it, I a using MAMP, (PHP version 7.4.16).

The entire configuration went well but after the install, I cannot neither go on my front or back-end, I have an error message because firefox won't connect, I am thinking of what I do and what can be the cause to this problem and in final, it is really wierd because I'm in a localhost so the problem is maybe not the server, I don't know.

If you ever have this problem and solved it, what did you do, I really need to find a solution quick for my job, I'm not a developper and my informatic skills are very limited.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: _"I have an error message because firefox won't connect"_ - which error? Did you research it?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't really know I'm sorry, I just had the localhost page active, when I try to connect to my webside changing the URL, I have a connection failed message, but the specific error isn't notified... I try to research it too but it seems that other people have different problems that I have, and I read a lot of topics about it

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug mode

```
config/defines.inc.php
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

And check the error message.
If the error message doesn't help you fix the error either, update your post and put it in the error message, and someone will definitely be able to help.

Or maybe you can try in another browser (for example Chrome).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I enable the debug mode as you said changing the "false" value to "true", but the page did not change, I have no more informations about my error. I think my route isn't good but I have the exact name of my directory, so I don't really know were the problem is, and it is not working on Edge or Chrome when I checked.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot from the page and the URL? 
And also, please attach the MAMP folder structure where you installed the PrestaShop